# Ifexists() tsql looping issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @tag VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @TagID as INT;
DECLARE @ID as INT;
DECLARE tag_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT tagname FROM #temptag  
 FOR READ ONLY
  OPEN tag_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor INTO @tag
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
          BEGIN              

            IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Tag WHERE TagName=@tag) 
                   BEGIN
                       print 1;
                   END 
                      print 2;
                      /* INSERT INTO Tag
                       SELECT @tag FROM #temptag 
                       SELECT @TagID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 

                       print @TagID*/
                FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor INTO @tag
                     END

           CLOSE  tag_cursor   
           DEALLOCATE tag_cursor
```

In my stored procedure I am searching for a value in the table. If the value already exists then I should not insert value.

so I have written

```
      IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Tag WHERE TagName=@tag) 
               BEGIN
                   print 1;
               END 
                  print 2;
                  /* INSERT INTO Tag
                   SELECT @tag FROM #temptag 
                   SELECT @TagID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 

                   print @TagID*/
            FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor INTO @tag
                 END
```

Problem: When I run it both values print1 and print 2 are getting printed

Can someone help me in fixing the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to have an `ELSE` block?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Tag WHERE TagName=@tag) 
BEGIN
    print 1;
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
    print 2;
    /* INSERT INTO Tag
       SELECT @tag FROM #temptag 
       SELECT @TagID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 

       print @TagID*/
END
```